# STM32F4 Discovery USB in HS mode?

Tags: usb, hid, libusb, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I want to convert the USB HID MOUSE demonstration example (from the STM32F4 Discovery board firmware package) into HIGH SPEED and be able to transfer 128Bytes in a single Xfer.

I changed the following places;

```
HID REPORT;
REPORT_SIZE (8)
REPORT_COUNT(128)
(report descriptor works properly under FS)

USBD_HID_CfgDesc;
wMaxPacketSize = 128

USBD_DeviceDesc;
bMaxPacketSize = 128

USBD_Init(&USB_OTG_dev,
            USB_OTG_HS_CORE_ID,
            &USR_desc,
            &USBD_HID_cb,
            &USR_cb);

HID_IN_PACKET              128
HID_OUT_PACKET             128
```

When i run, nothing happened on PC side. Its not even detected.

Please help me on that matter.
Which settings i need to change?

Comment: Your host operating system is probably unwilling to recognize a "mouse" claiming to be a high speed device.  You would also need to move the identification pullup resistor as for full speed, and be able to disable it.

Comment: But in that case, i'd expect an UNIDENTIFIED DEVICE warning, isn't that true? (I use Windows7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HS mode on all STM32F4 need external PHY

Comment: But there is an option USE_EMBEDDED_PHY. I'm very confused :(

Comment: embedded phy support only FS mode

Comment: I think that's right. Thanks anyway.

From STM32F407 datasheet;

-USB 2.0 full-speed device/host/OTG controller with on-chip PHY.

-USB 2.0 high-speed/full-speed device/host/OTG controller with
dedicated DMA, on-chip full-speed PHY and ULPI.